# To take notes or not to

Tags: soft-question, education

Is it really better to take notes as a maths major or are some better without them? I've never gotten used to taking notes and I've never done it. But I'm wondering if I'd improve if I'd start doing it.

I'm not sure how to label this. This is not a question about your preferences. I want concrete answers.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a matter of preference and/or habit rather than a need. Although, you never know if you need notes until you've made some...

Comment: Well, this should probably go to Mathematics Meta.

Comment: @quapka No, it should not; Meta would definitely not be the right place to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure where it should go? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for here. An in-depth study by someone in the field of mathematics education?

Comment: Preferably, if it exists.

Comment: If you can follow the lecture while you take notes, OK. But some  (of my) students are so obsessed with copying *all* from the blackboard that are unable to understand the subject!

Comment: One tip: If you take notes because you think the material will be useful in the future, remember there are math books that surely contain everything contained in the lectures, so if you are going to do it, don't do it just for that.

Answer (score 6):

From the first page of [this article](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~krasny/math156_crlt.pdf):

> Research on notetaking indicates that taking notes in class and reviewing those notes (either in class or
>   afterward) have a positive impact on student learning. Not surprisingly, the preponderance of studies
>   confirms that students recall more lecture material if they record it in their notes (Bligh, 2000). Students
>   who take notes score higher on both immediate and delayed tests of recall and synthesis than students
>   who do not take notes (Kiewra et al., 1991). Moreover, the more students record, the more they
>   remember and the better they perform on exams (Johnstone & Su, 1994). In summary, notetaking
>   facilitates both recall of factual material and the synthesis and application of new knowledge,
>   particularly when notes are reviewed prior to exams.

For what it's worth, my *strong* preference was always to take notes.

Comment: If only I could experience any counter arguments.